# How to make a kind of pivot with strings?

Tags: excel

I have a table like

```
+-----+--------+---------+
| URL | Label  | Value   |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u1  | label3 | param1  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u2  | label2 | param3  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u3  | label1 | param2  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u2  | label4 | param5  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u1  | label6 | param4  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u3  | label5 | param6  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u3  | label3 | param11 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u2  | label5 | param15 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u1  | label1 | param8  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u2  | label6 | param18 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u1  | label5 | param16 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u3  | label2 | param9  |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u3  | label4 | param14 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u2  | label3 | param12 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u1  | label2 | param10 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u3  | label6 | param17 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u1  | label4 | param13 |
+-----+--------+---------+
| u2  | label1 | param7  |
+-----+--------+---------+
```

Labels and values are alphanumeric strings.

I want to shorten the table and place each label into own column and values into url rows, so the table become looking like

```
+-----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| url | label1 | label2  | label3  | label4  | label5  | label6  |
+-----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| u1  | param8 | param10 | param1  | param13 | param16 | param4  |
+-----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| u2  | param7 | param3  | param12 | param5  | param15 | param18 |
+-----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| u3  | param2 | param9  | param11 | param14 | param6  | param17 |
+-----+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I tried to build a pivot - and got it partly work: urls are as column, labels are like headings of own columns - but pivot seems to only calculate, and I failed on getting values displayed.

What is the way for such table transformation?

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested about formula and have `Excel O365` then try below as per my screenshot.

```
F3=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A19))
G2=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B19)))
G3=XLOOKUP(1,($A$2:$A$19=$F3)*($B$2:$B$19=G$2),$C$2:$C$19)
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** You can use `#` to automatically fill formulas till end of row & column.

```
=XLOOKUP(F3#&G2#,A2:A19&B2:B19,C2:C19)
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW, your G3 formula needs to be filled into the table, right?  An alternative that spills is `=XLOOKUP(F2#&"_"&G1#,A2:A19&"_"&B2:B19,C2:C19,,0)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks Chris. I forgot that such magic behavior of `#` in Excel365. Will update my answer.

Comment: I have Office360 (https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1467/6347970196.png), but your formula isn't recognized as a formula. `XLookup` is unknown to my Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

`Power Query` has a "do not aggregate" option for pivot which would accomplish what you state.

To use Power Query,

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in the data
//  change Table name in next line to actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"URL", type text}, {"Label", type text}, {"Value", type text}}),

//Pivot on the SortedLabel column with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", 
        List.Sort(List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Label]),Order.Ascending), "Label", "Value")
        
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]